# How to work with array JSON in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm a JavaScript Programmer and has a project with PHP.
I'm having trouble with working JSON with PHP.

This is my JSON

```
{
   "orders":[
  {
     "name":"#1002"
  },
  {
     "name":"#1001"
  }
  ]
}
```

I need to get each name and echo them, I tried the following code `$myarray = json_decode($order, true)` but it returns me this error.

Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

How can i convert the json from array to string? or am i doing it wrong.

Comment: have you convert the JSON to string in your javascript something like `JSON.stringify(myjson)`?

Comment: Show us how you are saving the json on $order variable

Comment: `print_r($order);` check your array and fine the json index and update the `json_decode`function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.php

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('db_school',$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userlogin";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] =array(
        'id'=>$row['id'],
        'username'=>$row['username'],
        'userpass'=>$row['userpass'],
    );
}
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$data));
 ?>
```

view.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" border="1">
        <thead><tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'config.php',
        }).done(function(res) {
            var res_data = JSON.parse(res),table='';
            $.each(res_data.data,function(index, el) {
                console.log(el.id,' ', el.username,' ',el.userpass);
                table+='<tr>';                
                table+='<td>'+el.id+'</td>';                
                table+='<td>'+el.username+'</td>';                
                table+='<td>'+el.userpass+'</td>';                
                table+='</tr>';                
            });
            $('#tbl').html(table);
        });
    </script>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've seen a lot using this method, do you have a video tutorial or reference url for this?

Comment: This is my YouTube Chanel.
www.somelesson.blogspot.com
https://www.youtube.com/rampukarinfo

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the json response on a variable. And then do json_decode

```
$orders = '{
       "orders":[
         {
            "name":"#1002"
         },
         {
            "name":"#1001"
         }
      ]
}';
$myarray = json_decode($orders, true);
```

Now performing print_r will yield result like

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myarray);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [orders] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #1002
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #1001
                )

        )

)
```

**EDIT :**

In order to get only name values simply run a foreach

```
$result = [];
foreach($myarray['orders'] as $value) {
    $result[] = $value['name'];
}
```

Now printing $result you will get

```
Array
(
    [0] => #1002
    [1] => #1001
)
```

Comment: but i want the result be like this:
#1002
#1001

and not like the result with print_R

Comment: I don't get it. You mean, you want it like ['#1002', '#1001']?

Comment: Then 


`foreach($myarray as $order) {
   echo $order['name'];
}`